# 'Emgu.CV.Invoke' threw an exception

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am relativity new EmguCV but I have done a lot of research and read a few tutorials and look through this site for the answer. All of the other people with similar problems are told to add the unmangaged dll to the output folder. I have done this and I am still getting this error 'Emgu.CV.Invoke' threw an exception.

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

using AForge;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Video.VFW;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class SandBox : Form
    {
        private bool DeviceExist = false;
        public VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideoSource;
        public FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;
        private Capture capture;
        private VideoWriter captureOutput;


        private void FinalVideoSource_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgseventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY);
        pictureBox1.Image = image;
    }
    public SandBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = " ";
        FPS.Text = " ";
        try
        {
            VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(AForge.Video.DirectShow.FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            DeviceExist = true;
            foreach (AForge.Video.DirectShow.FilterInfo VideoCaptureDevice in VideoCaptureDevices)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(VideoCaptureDevice.Name);
            }
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        catch (ApplicationException)
        {
            DeviceExist = false;
            comboBox1.Items.Add("No device on your system");
        }
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FinalVideoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(VideoCaptureDevices[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        FinalVideoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideoSource_NewFrame);
        FinalVideoSource.Start();

        label1.Text = "Device running...";
        Start.Enabled = false;
        Stop.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Enabled = true;

        capture = new Capture();
        captureOutput = new VideoWriter("test.avi", 30, 1280, 720, true);
        Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
        captureOutput.WriteFrame(ImageFrame);
    }
}
```

The error is being thrown in line `capture = new Capture();`. I cant figure out what is wrong with the project. Just to clarify I am only using EmguCV to record video not to display it on screen. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: bear with me for not being an emgu user, but you'd better decide if you want aforge *or* emgu. also, in your Start_Click method, it seems you're trying to open the (possibly same) device first from aforge, then again from emgu. that won't work. you can only use a single webcam once in your prog.

Comment: Ok ill take a look at using only Emgu or only aforge thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception its means that EMGU.CV file is not dectecting by code. this is due to system dependency. you need to go in to configration manger window in visual stdio and choose your required platform and then copy respective dll files(64 dll files forx64 and 32bit dll for x86 can be downloaded from emgu website ) according to your platform. copile it now there is no error like emgu.cv.invoke
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_EMGU_C_Sharp